# the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "SimpleCircle::GetRadius"

Tags: c++

1. I use a const method GetRadius and a const SimpleCircle & rhs. I call a const method with a const objectas in the example of the Jesse Liberty's book.
2. Warning  C26444  Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction

I don`t understand where the problem is.

```
class SimpleCircle {
public:
    SimpleCircle(); 
    SimpleCircle(int);
    SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle&);
    ~SimpleCircle();
    void SetRadius(int);
    const int GetRadius();
    const SimpleCircle& operator++();
    const SimpleCircle operator++(int);
    const SimpleCircle& operator=(SimpleCircle&);

private:
    int* itsRadius;
};
SimpleCircle::SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle & rhs)
{
    int temp = rhs.GetRadius();
    itsRadius = new int(temp);
}
const int SimpleCircle::GetRadius()
{
    return *itsRadius;
}
const SimpleCircle& SimpleCircle::operator++() 
{
    ++(*itsRadius);
    return *this;
}

const SimpleCircle SimpleCircle::operator++(int theFlag)
{
    SimpleCircle temp(*this);
    ++(*itsRadius);
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    SimpleCircle Circle1;
    SimpleCircle Circle2(9);
    cout << "Circle1=" << Circle1.GetRadius() << endl << "Circle2=" << Circle2.GetRadius()<<endl;
    ++Circle1;
    Circle2++; //here is the warning, it`s done like ++Circle2
    cout << "After ++Circle1=" << Circle1.GetRadius() << endl << "++Circle2=" << Circle2.GetRadius() << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks, now it works! I have the latest Visual Studio, maybe, the book is too old

Comment: I wonder why itsRadius is a pointer instead of just a normal int

Comment: just a task from book